# find and remove specific R version

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio-server

I tried to install the latest version of R (4.2.1) for our RStudio Server (Workbench) and I see the version of R in the drop down menu from within the server:

[image]

However, I'm unsure exactly where this install is located in the system. I've tried `which R` and this returns:

/usr/local/bin/R

This seems to be the 4.0.5 version. Can someone help an ubuntu novice with the following:

- locate the path of the installed 4.2.1 version
- remove this install
- ensure a new install is placed in the right location (i will follow this https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r/)

thanks

Comment: OK thanks. I think I've located it under ```opt/R/``` but I'm still not sure how I either a) run this version specifically within the terminal, or b) how I would go about uninstalling this specific version. Also, for info, the way I located this was by selecting that version in RStudio and running ```.libPaths()```

Comment: Glad you found the `/opt/R/...` path, not sure how to configure, but I suspect "which version of R to prefer" is a per-user thing, not necessarily a per-server thing. Sorry I can't help with that aspect.

Comment: Thanks but I still have no idea how you remove a specific version of R

Comment: `apt-get uninstall specific-version-r`? Removing it depends on your OS.

Comment: I mean ... `sudo apt-get remove r-4.0.5`?